# Cannot find 'fromJavadoc' when generating Apache Camel Component

Tags: maven, apache-camel

I'm attempting to use the Apache Camel API Component Framework to generate a Component for the CloudFoundary UAA API. I followed the instructions from the [docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.5/html/apache_camel_development_guide/apicompframework) to generate the Component project and update the pom to pull in the CF client lib and Javadoc. When I try to run the Maven build to generate the Component source code, I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.camel:camel-api-component-maven-plugin:3.21.0:fromApis for parameter fromJavadoc: Cannot find 'fromJavadoc' in class org.apache.camel.maven.ApiProxy

**fromJavadoc** is part of the generated pom and necessary to tell the Camel api plugin to get the relevant metadata from the associated Javadoc dependency. This is the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven- 
v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
  <groupId>org.uaa.component.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>uaa-component-example-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>uaa-component-example</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Camel UaaExample Component</name>
<description>Camel Component for UaaExample</description>

<properties>
  <schemeName>uaa</schemeName>
  <componentName>UaaExample</componentName>
  <componentPackage>org.uaa.component.example</componentPackage>
  <outPackage>org.uaa.component.example.internal</outPackage>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- support camel documentation -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>apt</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Camel annotations in provided scope to avoid compile errors in IDEs -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>spi-annotations</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


<!-- logging -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- testing -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- uaa client api and javadoc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudfoundry-client-reactor</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudfoundry-client-reactor</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.0.RELEASE</version>
    <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

<plugins>
  
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <!-- to generate the MANIFEST-FILE of the bundle -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <instructions>
        <Bundle-Name>Camel Component for ${componentName}</Bundle-Name>
        <Bundle-SymbolicName>org.uaa.component.example.uaa-component-example</Bundle-SymbolicName>
        <Export-Service>org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver;component=${schemeName}</Export-Service>
        <Export-Package>${componentPackage};version=${project.version}</Export-Package>
        <Import-Package>
          ${componentPackage}.api;version=${project.version},
          ${componentPackage};version=${project.version},
          org.apache.camel.*;version=${camelVersion}
        </Import-Package>
        <Private-Package>${outPackage}</Private-Package>
        <Implementation-Title>Apache Camel</Implementation-Title>
        <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
        <Karaf-Info>Camel;${project.artifactId}=${project.version}</Karaf-Info>
        <_versionpolicy>[$(version;==;$(@)),$(version;+;$(@)))</_versionpolicy>
        <_failok>false</_failok>
      </instructions>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <!-- generate Component source and test source -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-api-component-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-test-component-classes</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>fromApis</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <apis>
            <api>
              <apiName>hello-uaa</apiName>
              <proxyClass>org.cloudfoundry.uaa.UaaClient</proxyClass>
              <fromJavadoc/>
            </api>
          </apis>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

  <!-- generate components meta-data and validate component includes documentation etc -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${camelVersion}</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>prepare</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-components</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>validate</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>validate-components</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

  <!-- add generated source and test source to build -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>add-generated-sources</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/camel-component</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>add-generated-test-sources</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-test-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/camel-component</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

</plugins>

<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-api-component-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${camelVersion}</version>
      <configuration>
        <scheme>uaa</scheme>
        <componentName>Uaa</componentName>
        <componentPackage>org.uaa.component.example.generated</componentPackage>
        <outPackage>org.uaa.component.example</outPackage>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>

</build>

<reporting>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-api-component-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${camelVersion}</version>
    <configuration>
      <scheme>${schemeName}</scheme>
      <componentName>${componentName}</componentName>
      <componentPackage>${componentPackage}</componentPackage>
      <outPackage>${outPackage}</outPackage>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</reporting>

</project>
```

Any thought on what I may be doing wrong here? Thanks!